# Xcode 6.1+ iOS SDK 8.1 UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode6.1

I have one problem regarding UITableview running with Xcode 6.1 + iOS SDK 8.1.

I have one simple single view application, something strange happened when i was using storyboard to create a tableview.

Inside of my viewDidLoad, I wrote this code:

```
UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];    
[tableView registerClass:[NameAndColorCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

added/edited:

```
UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

NSLog(@"Table View Tag = %ld", (long)tableView.tag);


[tableView registerClass:[NameAndColorCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UIEdgeInsets contentInset = tableView.contentInset;
contentInset.top = 20;
[tableView setContentInset:contentInset];
```

But the tableView is always nil, and eventually caused my App crashed.

I checked with my View Controller's View, both "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes" were enabled.

After I disabled "Use Size Classes", everything went back normal. I mean, tableView was created successfully.

Has anyone met the same issue? Is this a bug from Xcode? or I made some mistake?

Please help me, Thanks a lot !

Best Regards,
Rui

Comment: Every time I have had a problem like this with a table view, the problem has been that I have not wired up the table view to the view comtroller in the storyboard/xib.

Comment: This does not make sense. "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes" are not responsible for your table view being nil. As long as you have added your table view in the view controller in your storyboard and you know that it has indeed a tag value of 1, you shouldn't have any issues. You should provide us with more code to figure out what is wrong. @MahatmaManic even though he refers to the tableView in an "unorthodox" manner, this is not an unconnected IBOutlet issue.

Comment: @DonMiguel, the source code is quite straightforward. I already set the tag view to 1, inside table view's attributes inspector.